# Vaadin7 drag and drop identifying Target component

Tags: drag-and-drop, vaadin, vaadin7

I can get the source component form DragAndDropEvent by the following way:

```
final DataBoundTransferable t = (DataBoundTransferable) event.getTransferable();
Component from = t.getSourceComponent();
```

How can I get the target component from DragAndDropEvent? (The component where the mouse was released.) Sadly there is no t.getTargetComponent()...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [Drag & Drop secion of the book of vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/advanced.dragndrop.html)

The event.getTargetDetails() should be what you search

```
public void drop(DragAndDropEvent event) {
        // Wrapper for the object that is dragged
        Transferable t = event.getTransferable();

        // Make sure the drag source is the same tree
        if (t.getSourceComponent() != tree)
            return;

        TreeTargetDetails target = (TreeTargetDetails)
            event.getTargetDetails();
        ....
```